# how do I check the size of a text typed in an input? React-Native

Tags: react-native, input

I need to verify that the text is less than 11 characters
how I did this?

(sorry about my english)

Comment: Do add some sample code which shows what you have tried so far. SO is not a forum to get your tasks done.

Comment: Please read this article on how to ask a question on stack overflow. as @MadhukarMohanraju pointed out stack overflow is not meant to be used to do the work for you. Stack overflow expects that you have made an attempt to solve the problem for yourself https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that the length of input text < 11 is pretty simple. You can do it like this:

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    if (text.length < 11) {
      this.setState({text});
    } else {
      this.setState({errorMessage: 'Text input must be less than 11'});
    }
  }}
  value={this.state.text}
/>
```

What you also need to consider is how you want to present this information to the user. (i.e. some sort of error message to notify them of this problem, so they know what is happening)

For reference, please consider reading the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

React-native documentation is generally excellent. Just go through the **Components** list and read up on these things.